# How to handle invalid SSL certificates with Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, ssl, https, apache-commons-httpclient

I know, there are many different questions and so many answers about this problem... But I can't understand...

I have: ubuntu-9.10-desktop-amd64 + NetBeans6.7.1 installed "as is" from off. rep.
I need connecting to some site over the HTTPS. For this I use Apache's HttpClient.

From tutorial I read:

"Once you have JSSE correctly installed, secure HTTP communication over SSL should be as
 simple as plain HTTP communication." And some example:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod("https://www.verisign.com/"); 
try { 
  httpclient.executeMethod(httpget);
  System.out.println(httpget.getStatusLine());
} finally {
  httpget.releaseConnection();
}
```

By now, I write this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpMethod get = new GetMethod("https://mms.nw.ru");
//get.setDoAuthentication(true);

try {
    int status = client.executeMethod(get);
    System.out.println(status);

    BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(get.getResponseBodyAsStream());
    int r=0;byte[] buf = new byte[10];
    while((r = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
        System.out.write(buf,0,r);
    }

} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

As a result I have a set of errors:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1627)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:204)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:198)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:994)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:142)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:533)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:471)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:904)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1132)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:643)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:78)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
        at simpleapachehttp.Main.main(Main.java:41)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:302)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:205)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:235)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:147)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:973)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:191)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:255)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:297)
        ... 23 more
```

What have I to do to create simplest SSL connection?
(Probably without KeyManager and Trust manager etc. while.)

Comment: That particular site's SSL cert isn't setup correctly. When I go to https://mms.nw.ru, I get a error screen in Chrome.

Comment: First of all import you'r crt file into {JAVA_HOME}/jre/security/cacerts, if you still faced with this exception, change you'r jdk version. For example from jdk1.8.0_17 to jdk1.8.0_231

Answer (score 166, accepted):

https://mms.nw.ru uses a self-signed certificate that's not in the default trust manager set. To resolve the issue, do one of the following:

- Configure `SSLContext` with a `TrustManager` that accepts any certificate (see below).
- Configure `SSLContext` with an appropriate trust store that includes your certificate.
- Add the certificate for that site to the default Java trust store.

Here's a program that creates a (mostly worthless) SSL Context that accepts any certificate:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class SSLTest {
    
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        // configure the SSLContext with a TrustManager
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

        URL url = new URL("https://mms.nw.ru");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    
    private static class DefaultTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this approach be integrated with HttpClient instead of a URLConnection?

Comment: Yeah, the HttpClient docs should tell you how to plug in your own SSLContext

Comment: You can plug in an `SSLContext` with Apache HTTP Client 3.x using this: http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/wiki/ApacheHttpClientUsage   There's native support for using an `SSLContext` in Apache HTTP Client 4.x now.

Comment: It should of course be noted that this approach (SSL Context that accepts any cert) makes the connection vulnerable to active MITM attacks.

Comment: FYI SSLContext.setDefault() is a java 1.7+ method.

Comment: this trustmanager entry solved my javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Update for version 4.3: SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).useTLS().build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory connectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());

Comment: Rather than setting as default, you can set it for just that connection. `conn.setSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory())`

Comment: Thanks, this also solved a issue we had with a RMI connection (over SSL)

Comment: FYI I try to group this tips into a single helper : [UnsafeSSLHelper](https://github.com/boly38/javabox/blob/master/src/main/java/org/internetresources/util/UnsafeSSLHelper.java). You could try it using Apache HttpClient 4.3.6. `UnsafeSSLHelper unsafeSSLHelper = new UnsafeSSLHelper();    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSslcontext(unsafeSSLHelper.createUnsecureSSLContext()).setHostnameVerifier(unsafeSSLHelper.getPassiveX509HostnameVerifier()).build();`

Comment: How we can implement the same code in HttpClient API and in RestTemplates ? Please help... regards, Neha

Comment: I was wondering.. Why so many developers insist in this approach of accepting every SSL certificate? IMHO, it is totally against the purpose of the solution (encryption of HTTP traffic).

Comment: Make sure u have right SSL context e.g. :
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

Comment: Hi, can you help me solve this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57224929/how-can-i-fix-a-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-er?noredirect=1#comment100954750_57224929 It is very similar.  I want to try and fix it using conda if possible so I can export an environment that works.

Comment: It needs to be noted, and you should have noted yourself, that the trust manager posted in this answer is radically insecure. You should not use this code.

Answer (score 47):

https://mms.nw.ru likely uses a certificate not issued by a certification authority. Consequently, you need to add the certificate to your trusted Java key store as explained in [unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification):

> When working on a client that works
>   with an SSL enabled server running in
>   https protocol, you could get error
>   'unable to find valid certification
>   path to requested target' if the
>   server certificate is not issued by
>   certification authority, but a self
>   signed or issued by a private CMS.
>
> Don't panic. All you need to do is to
>   add the server certificate to your
>   trusted Java key store if your client
>   is written in Java. You might be
>   wondering how as if you can not access
>   the machine where the server is
>   installed. There is a simple program
>   can help you. Please download the [Java
>   program](http://web.archive.org/web/20150923060127/http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java) and run
>
> ```
> % java InstallCert _web_site_hostname_
> ```
>
> This program opened a connection to
>   the specified host and started an SSL
>   handshake. It printed the exception
>   stack trace of the error that occured
>   and shows you the certificates used by
>   the server. Now it prompts you add the
>   certificate to your trusted KeyStore.
>
> If you've changed your mind, enter
>   'q'. If you really want to add the
>   certificate, enter '1', or other
>   numbers to add other certificates,
>   even a CA certificate, but you usually
>   don't want to do that. Once you have
>   made your choice, the program will
>   display the complete certificate and
>   then added it to a Java KeyStore named
>   'jssecacerts' in the current
>   directory.
>
> To use it in your program, either
>   configure JSSE to use it as its trust
>   store or copy it into your
>   $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security directory.
>   If you want all Java applications to
>   recognize the certificate as trusted
>   and not just JSSE, you could also
>   overwrite the cacerts file in that
>   directory.
>
> After all that, JSSE will be able to
>   complete a handshake with the host,
>   which you can verify by running the
>   program again.
>
> To get more details, you can check out
>   Leeland's blog [No more 'unable to find
>   valid certification path to requested
>   target'](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target)

Comment: You cant add an SSL certificate for every single website in the world that has an invalid ssl certificate.

Comment: @Jacob, Pascal is right, you should verify the certificate of the site you're connecting to. Authenticating the server is an essential part of securing the SSL connection.

Comment: A slightly modified version of that program is avaialble at http://infposs.blogspot.it/2013/06/installcert-and-java-7.html

It solves an issue with Java 7 (an UnsupportedOperationExcetpion when you run InstallCert the second time to check whether the certificate has been correctly installed).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't support proxies.

Comment: The "Java program" link in the answer leads to an awful page on the all-but-dead (for good reason!) Google Code, filled with dozens of files, with _no_ indication that you actually only need a single `.java` file... or where to start. The link posted by @Pino makes it easy to see... how simple this actually is. Grazie Pino!

Answer (score 23):

In addition to Pascal Thivent's correct answer, another way is to save the certificate from Firefox (View Certificate -> Details -> export) or `openssl s_client` and import it into the trust store.

You should only do this if you have a way to verify that certificate. Failing that, do it the first time you connect, it will at least give you an error if the certificate changes unexpectedly on subsequent connections.

To import it in a trust store, use:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore truststore.jks -file servercert.pem
```

By default, the default trust store should be `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` and its password should be `changeit`, see [JSSE Reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization) for details.

If you don't want to allow that certificate globally, but only for these connections, it's possible to create an `SSLContext` for it:

```
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/.../truststore.jks");
ks.load(fis, null);
// or ks.load(fis, "thepassword".toCharArray());
fis.close();

tmf.init(ks);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

Then, you need to set it up for Apache HTTP Client 3.x by implementing one if its [`SecureProtocolSocketFactory`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/protocol/SecureProtocolSocketFactory.html) to use this `SSLContext`. (There are examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/wiki/ApacheHttpClientUsage)).

Apache HTTP Client 4.x (apart from the earliest version) has direct support for passing an `SSLContext`.

Answer (score 18):

For Apache HttpClient 4.5+ & Java8:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial((chain, authType) -> true).build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory =
        new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new String[]
        {"SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3", "TLSv1","TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2" }, null,
        NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
        .build();
```

**But if your HttpClient use a ConnectionManager for seeking connection, e.g. like this:**

```
 PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new 
         PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

 CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .build();
```

**The `HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)` has no effect**, the problem is not resolved.

Because that the HttpClient use the specified connectionManager for seeking connection and the specified connectionManager haven't register our customized SSLConnectionSocketFactory. To resolve this, should register the The customized SSLConnectionSocketFactory in the connectionManager. The correct code should like this:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new 
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(RegistryBuilder.
                <ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
      .register("http",PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
      .register("https", sslConnectionSocketFactory).build());

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .build();
```

Comment: You saved my day! I kept wondering why setSSLSocketFactory had no effect whatsoever. I didn't realize that I had to register my factory to the connection manager instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

The Apache HttpClient 4.5 way:

```
org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContextBuilder.create();
sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
SSLContext sslContext = sslContextBuilder.build();
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory =
        new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier());

HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();
```

NOTE: `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder` is **deprecated** and `org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder` is the new one (notice `conn` missing from the latter's package name).

Comment: Checking the code of 4.5: SSLContextBuilder since 4.4 - NOT depricated.
TrustSelfSignedStrategy since 4.1 - NOT deprecated.
SSLConnectionSocketFactory some constructors are deprecated, the one in the example is NOT.
DefaultHostnameVerifier since 4.4 - NOT deprecated.

Comment: Deprecated and moved to org.apache.http.conn.ssl

Comment: With this I have a strange effect: running from console it´s working (ignoring the host and cert validity)
If I run it from eclipse it fails with " sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Answer (score 10):

From http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html:

```
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", 
new Protocol("https", new MySSLSocketFactory(), 443));
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod("https://www.whatever.com/");
try {
  httpclient.executeMethod(httpget);
      System.out.println(httpget.getStatusLine());
} finally {
      httpget.releaseConnection();
}
```

Where MySSLSocketFactory example can be found [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/contrib/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.java?view=markup). It references a `TrustManager`, which you can modify to trust everything (although you must consider this!)

Answer (score 10):

want to paste the answer here:

in Apache HttpClient 4.5.5

[How to handle invalid SSL certificate with Apache client 4.5.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368146/how-to-handle-invalid-ssl-certificate-with-apache-client-4-5-5)

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients
            .custom()
            .setSSLContext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE).build())
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
            .build();
```

Comment: from which package is SSLContextBuilder?

Comment: @zygimantus I have used from this one " import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder "

Answer (score 6):

Once you have a Java Cert Store (by using the *great* InstallCert class created above), you can get java to use it by passing the "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" param at java startup.

Ex:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/jssecacerts MyClassName
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day! I thought that when you were using /jre for JAVA_HOME, the `/jre/lib/security/cacerts` file would be used but.. obviously it was not the case and your setting just magically made everything work.. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another issue you may run into with self signed test certs is this:

java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong: should be ...

This error occurs when you are trying to access a HTTPS url. You might have already installed the server certificate to your JRE's keystore. But this error means that the name of the server certificate does not match with the actual domain name of the server that is mentioned in the URL. This normally happens when you are using a non CA issued certificate.

This example shows how to write a HttpsURLConnection DefaultHostnameVerifier that ignore the certificates server name:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=211

Comment: Link is broken :(

Answer (score 3):

EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory was giving me problems so I ended up implementing my own ProtocolSocketFactory.

First you need to register it:

```
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", new TrustAllSSLSocketFactory(), 443));

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
...
```

Then implement ProtocolSocketFactory:

```
class TrustAllSSLSocketFactory implements ProtocolSocketFactory {

    public static final TrustManager[] TRUST_ALL_CERTS = new TrustManager[]{
        new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] certs, final String authType) {

            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] certs, final String authType) {

            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

    private TrustManager[] getTrustManager() {
        return TRUST_ALL_CERTS;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(final String host, final int port, final InetAddress clientHost,
                               final int clientPort) throws IOException {
        return getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port, clientHost, clientPort);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final String host, final int port, final InetAddress localAddress,
                               final int localPort, final HttpConnectionParams params) throws IOException {
        return createSocket(host, port);
    }

    public Socket createSocket(final String host, final int port) throws IOException {
        return getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port);
    }

    private SocketFactory getSocketFactory() throws UnknownHostException {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = getTrustManager();

        try {
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            context.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

            final SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
            return socketFactory;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException exception) {
            throw new UnknownHostException(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This is with HttpClient 3.1 and Java 8

Comment: still getting an exception!

Answer (score 2):

For a way to easily add hosts you trust at runtime without throwing out all checks, try the code here: http://code.google.com/p/self-signed-cert-trust-manager/.

Answer (score 1):

I happened to face the same issue, all of a sudden all my imports were missing. I tried deleting all the contents in my .m2 folder. And trying to re-import everything , but still nothing worked.
Finally what I did was opened the website for which the IDE was complaining that it couldn't download in my browser. And saw the certificate it was using, and saw in my

```sh
$ keytool -v -list  PATH_TO_JAVA_KEYSTORE
```

Path to my keystore was /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts

that particular certificate was not there.

So all you have to do is put the certificate into the JAVA JVM keystore again.
It can be done using the below command.

```sh
$ keytool -import -alias ANY_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_GIVE -file PATH_TO_YOUR_CERTIFICATE -keystore PATH_OF_JAVA_KEYSTORE
```

If it asks for password, try the default password 'changeit'
If you get permission error when running the above command.
In windows open it in administration mode.
In mac and unix use sudo.

After you have successfully added the key,
You can view it using :

```sh
$ keytool -v -list  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

You can view just the SHA-1 using teh command

```sh
$ keytool -list  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `InstallCert` to generate the `jssecacerts` file and do 
`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/jssecacerts` worked great.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://javaskeleton.blogspot.in/2010/07/avoiding-peer-not-authenticated-with.html) explains the requirement you have step by step. If You are not really concerned which certificate you can proceed with the process in below link.

Note You might want to double check what you are doing since, this is a unsafe operation.

Comment: you should really put some of you own explanation or an example, an answer that just points to a link would be worthless if that link would ever break.

Answer (score 0):

I'm useing httpclient 3.1.X ,and this works for me

```
        try {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);
        SslContextSecureProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory = new SslContextSecureProtocolSocketFactory(sslContext,false);
        Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", (ProtocolSocketFactory) socketFactory, 443));//同样会影响到HttpUtils
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

### }

```
public class SslContextSecureProtocolSocketFactory implements      SecureProtocolSocketFactory {

private SSLContext sslContext;
private boolean verifyHostname;

public SslContextSecureProtocolSocketFactory(SSLContext sslContext, boolean verifyHostname) {
    this.verifyHostname = true;
    this.sslContext = sslContext;
    this.verifyHostname = verifyHostname;
}

public SslContextSecureProtocolSocketFactory(SSLContext sslContext) {
    this(sslContext, true);
}

public SslContextSecureProtocolSocketFactory(boolean verifyHostname) {
    this((SSLContext)null, verifyHostname);
}

public SslContextSecureProtocolSocketFactory() {
    this((SSLContext)null, true);
}

public synchronized void setHostnameVerification(boolean verifyHostname) {
    this.verifyHostname = verifyHostname;
}

public synchronized boolean getHostnameVerification() {
    return this.verifyHostname;
}

public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress clientHost, int clientPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    SSLSocketFactory sf = this.getSslSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket)sf.createSocket(host, port, clientHost, clientPort);
    this.verifyHostname(sslSocket);
    return sslSocket;
}

public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpConnectionParams params) throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
    if(params == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameters may not be null");
    } else {
        int timeout = params.getConnectionTimeout();
        Socket socket = null;
        SSLSocketFactory socketfactory = this.getSslSocketFactory();
        if(timeout == 0) {
            socket = socketfactory.createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort);
        } else {
            socket = socketfactory.createSocket();
            InetSocketAddress localaddr = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
            InetSocketAddress remoteaddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
            socket.bind(localaddr);
            socket.connect(remoteaddr, timeout);
        }

        this.verifyHostname((SSLSocket)socket);
        return socket;
    }
}

public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    SSLSocketFactory sf = this.getSslSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket)sf.createSocket(host, port);
    this.verifyHostname(sslSocket);
    return sslSocket;
}

public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    SSLSocketFactory sf = this.getSslSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket)sf.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    this.verifyHostname(sslSocket);
    return sslSocket;
}

private void verifyHostname(SSLSocket socket) throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException, UnknownHostException {
    synchronized(this) {
        if(!this.verifyHostname) {
            return;
        }
    }

    SSLSession session = socket.getSession();
    String hostname = session.getPeerHost();

    try {
        InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
    } catch (UnknownHostException var10) {
        throw new UnknownHostException("Could not resolve SSL sessions server hostname: " + hostname);
    }

    X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[])((X509Certificate[])session.getPeerCertificates());
    if(certs != null && certs.length != 0) {
        X500Principal subjectDN = certs[0].getSubjectX500Principal();
        List cns = this.getCNs(subjectDN);
        boolean foundHostName = false;
        Iterator i$ = cns.iterator();
        AntPathMatcher matcher  = new AntPathMatcher();
        while(i$.hasNext()) {
            String cn = (String)i$.next();
            if(matcher.match(cn.toLowerCase(),hostname.toLowerCase())) {
                foundHostName = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!foundHostName) {
            throw new SSLPeerUnverifiedException("HTTPS hostname invalid: expected \'" + hostname + "\', received \'" + cns + "\'");
        }
    } else {
        throw new SSLPeerUnverifiedException("No server certificates found!");
    }
}

private List<String> getCNs(X500Principal subjectDN) {
    ArrayList cns = new ArrayList();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(subjectDN.getName(), ",");

    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String cnField = st.nextToken();
        if(cnField.startsWith("CN=")) {
            cns.add(cnField.substring(3));
        }
    }

    return cns;
}

protected SSLSocketFactory getSslSocketFactory() {
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = null;
    synchronized(this) {
        if(this.sslContext != null) {
            sslSocketFactory = this.sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        }
    }

    if(sslSocketFactory == null) {
        sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    }

    return sslSocketFactory;
}

public synchronized void setSSLContext(SSLContext sslContext) {
    this.sslContext = sslContext;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For HttpClient, we can do this :

```
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

        String uri = new StringBuilder("url").toString();

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLContext(ctx)
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier).build()
```

Answer (score 0):

follow the instruction given below for Java 1.7, to create an SSL certificate using InstallCert.java program file.

https://github.com/escline/InstallCert

you must restart the tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Used the following along with DefaultTrustManager and it worked in httpclient like charm. Thanks a ton!! @Kevin and every other contributor

```
    SSLContext ctx = null;
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = null;
    try {

        ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

        sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                ctx,
                new String[] { "TLSv1" },
                null,
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();
```