# akka http SSLConfig issues with Hostname verification and cert validation

Tags: http, ssl, ssl-certificate, akka, hostname

I have some issues with Akka http configuration on the client side. I am trying to connect to a server which doesn't provide:
- a public signed certificate
- a certificate corresponding to the hostname
I don't have the hand on this nginx so I cannot change the server side configuration. I can only change the client side.

After lots of investigation on configuring SSL, I have found that I need to configure SSL options in **application.conf** at two different levels :

```
akka.ssl-config.ssl.loose.acceptAnyCertificate=true
akka.ssl-config.loose.disableHostnameVerification = true
```

and

```
ssl-config.loose.acceptAnyCertificate=true
ssl-config.loose.disableHostnameVerification = true
```

I have checked the configuration is fine with

```
log-config-on-start = "on"
```

The problem is that I still get error at  the akka debug level (not very clear)

```
[ingestionApiClient-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] [akka://ingestionApiClient/user/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-216-1-unknown-operation] closing output
```

Looking at wireshark I have found that's a problem of certificate validation

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Certificate Unknown)
```

I suppose the JVM configuration is overiding all I have done so I also tried to follow this method to modify JVM SSL config :
[Java SSL: how to disable hostname verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031258/java-ssl-how-to-disable-hostname-verification)

No problem with configuring the SSLContext and passing it to akka http because I can set the default HttpsContext with

```
val sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
*...configuration...*
val customContext =HttpsContext(sc, sslParameters = Some(params))
Http().setDefaultClientHttpsContext(customHttpsContext)
```

But I cannot find anyway to configure the default hostname verifier. The Http class doesn't have any method like `Http().setDefaultHostnameVerifier`

This how I connect to the server

```
val dataIngestFlow = Http().outgoingConnectionTls(config.httpEndpointHost,config.httpEndpointPort)
```

How can I achieve this ? Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of `akka` and `akka-http` you use but have you tried to set the configuration field `akka.ssl-config.hostnameVerifierClass` to your specific implementation of the `HostNameVerifier` interface?

The simplest verifier which accepts everything looks like this:

```
public static class AcceptAllHostNameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
  @Override
  public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck in similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47366039/1610034) and was getting similar [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47349020/1610034). with following code I was able to get through:

```
val trustStoreConfig = TrustStoreConfig(None, Some("/etc/Project/keystore/my.cer")).withStoreType("PEM")
val trustManagerConfig = TrustManagerConfig().withTrustStoreConfigs(List(trustStoreConfig))

val badSslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings(s => s.withLoose(s.loose
  .withAcceptAnyCertificate(true)
  .withDisableHostnameVerification(true)
).withTrustManagerConfig(trustManagerConfig))

val badCtx = Http().createClientHttpsContext(badSslConfig)

Http().superPool[RequestTracker](badCtx)(httpMat)
```