# Peer not authenticated in java

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have gone to almost all the post related to this exception. Actually my problem is I have an java application through which I am hitting an URL and getting response from it.

code to hit URL is :

```
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("https://urlto.esb.com");
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;       
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
```

Here I am getting `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`

So after some Google search I come to know that I can import certificate in keystore of java where the application is running. so I imported certificate in keystore and this code is working. but i don't want this solution so after some more searching I come to know that I can use `TrustManager` for the same thing without importing certificate into keystore. So I have written code like:

```
@Test
    public void withTrustManeger() throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = buildhttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://urlto.esb.com");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httpGet );

        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        inputStream.close();
        String jsonText = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(jsonText);
    }

    private DefaultHttpClient buildhttpClient() throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, getTrustingManager(), new java.security.SecureRandom());

        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(sc);
        Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory);
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);
        return httpclient;
    }

    private TrustManager[] getTrustingManager() {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                // Do nothing               
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                // Do nothing
            }

        } };
        return trustAllCerts;
    }
```

This code is also working but My question is I am not checking anything related to certificates then how connection is trusted. after debugging I come to know that only `checkServerTrusted` is hitting. So I have write something in `checkServerTrusted` to validate certificates that come in `certs` and the one which is in my application like some .cer or .crt file.

Every Help will be appreciated.

Update after @EpicPandaForce (Using Apache HttpClient 4.3)

```
        try 
        {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("E:\\Desktop\\esbcert\\keystore.jks");
            keyStore.load(inputStream, "key".toCharArray());
            SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(keyStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
            sslcontext = sslContextBuilder.build();
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext);
            HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://url.esb.com");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httpGet );

            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream httpStram = httpEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpStram));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            httpStram.close();
            inputStream.close();
            String jsonText = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(jsonText);

        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Loading keystore failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693991/java-ignore-expired-ssl-sertificate/8694377#8694377 ?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, Yes but how can I verify certificate. Means the one which is came from server with the one that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, seeing as you are using Apache HttpClient 4.x, a simpler solution would be the following:

```
    SSLContext sslcontext = null;
    try {
        SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
        sslcontext = sslContextBuilder.build();
```

Where `trustStore` is initialized like this

```
    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME); //you can use JKS if that is what you have
        InputStream inputStream = new File("pathtoyourkeystore");
        try {
            keyStore.load(inputStream, "password".toCharArray());
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Loading keystore failed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return keyStore;
}
```

And then create the HttpClient

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext);
httpclient = HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
```

EDIT: Exact code for me was this:

```
        SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
        sslcontext = sslContextBuilder.build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslcontext, new String[] {"TLSv1"}, null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
        );
        httpclient = HttpClients
            .custom()
            .setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
```

Comment: Oh by this I can load my keystore @ runtime, am i getting correctly?

Comment: Yup! But this makes your request trust only the certificate that you provided in the keystore. If you have that certificate in your app, you should be able to load it.

Comment: Perfect that's what i want. So what if i import the certificate in `cacerts` file in my development PC and while building jar i will copy this cacerts into my app and while making request i will load the keystore (cacerts from my app) as you shown in answer

Comment: I think you can do that, but I think the while `cacerts` file from the Java directory is overkill. If you have the `certificate` in your disposal, then you can create a new `JKS` keystore using `keytool` (so don't specify the `BouncyCastleProvider` as the provider, it is not needed), which would contain only the certificate you want. But `cacerts` would also work, the default password to the `cacerts` is `changeme`. You can put the `cacerts` keystore into the app and then access it in the classpath too (I think that's `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("...")`.

Comment: Okay, First I will try with creating my own `JKS` file using `keytool` and try to load it, If fails I come to you :). but just I have seen that classes [`SSLContextBuilder`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.html),[`SSLContexts`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLContexts.html) are from  HttpClient 4.3 and I am using 4.2.x

Comment: What will be provider in case of my own JKS file? or is it optional in 4.3?

Comment: Gah. it's not `changeme`, it's `changeit`. Sorry about that. The provider for the `KeyStore.getInstance(inputStream)` call will default to the first provider, which I believe will be the provider by `Sun`. I personally used the latest HttpClient, that's what I got the example from.

Comment: I have updated code in question, but my Junit test case getting failed. After debugging I come to know that it's getting failed at LOC `SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext);` no exception is thrown program is terminated. but in Junit window I got Error `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE` where I am doing wrong.

Comment: what version of HttpClient are you using exactly? As per the following constructor http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.html#SSLConnectionSocketFactory(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext) you are supposed to be able to use it. I used `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'` dependency in my android project where this code worked without a problem.

Comment: I added the exact code from my project, maybe that will fix it.

Comment: I am using HttpClient 4.4

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by this setting:

```
final SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf;

    try {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (cert, authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
        sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    final Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
            .register("https", sslsf)
            .build();
```