# How to Handle "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException", a Retrofit Error response?

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit

I'm writing an application where using Retrofit API for server communication. To test Back Date Scenario I modified Device Date fro current date. In response it giving following error log:

```
ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: Certificate not valid until Tue Jan 06 05:30:00 GMT+05:30 2015 (compared to Thu Nov 13 11:52:59 GMT+05:30 2014)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:241)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:174)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:120)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:131)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:312)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:235)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:262)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:219)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:192)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.newrelic.agent.android.instrumentation.okhttp2.CallExtension.execute(CallExtension.java:43)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at com.newrelic.agent.android.instrumentation.retrofit.ClientExtension.execute(ClientExtension.java:42)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
D/Retrofit(22305):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

In response I'm getting NETWORK as RetrofitError.getKind() object.

Any suggestion how else can filter it.

Comment: What is your server url?

Comment: @VaisakhN How that matter dear !

Comment: I think(may be wrong :)) your server certificate valid dates is not matching with your device date

Comment: You right here...I change my local device date that I mention in Question. But how to handle it from code that This Kind of error has occur. Since in error response we get error kind as 'Network' only. Any other suggestion !

Comment: You can't handle it from code. The certificate isn't valid at the time setting you're using. You'll have to use an older certificate somehow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693991/java-ignore-expired-ssl-certificate :-Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks...but error I'm getting is an valid scenario. Only thing that I wanted to know if there is way to know in program, that This error occur.

One partial way I found...Checked with Throwable instance if it's SSLHandshakeException...then this could be reason. But still Kind still same "Network" error.

Answer (score 0):

Start from RetrofitError error, get the Throwable with Throwable exc = error.getCause() and then check if (exc != null && exc instanceof SSLHandshakeException).
But i suggest you to use certificate pinning, to avoid this issues.

Comment: certificate pinning, what is this! Could you elaborate more.

Comment: Well, it's a way to trust a certificate. If you're using retrofit and OkHttp, I suggest to follow the example that you can find inside the [documentation](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/CertificatePinner.html)

Comment: @Shubh Have you tried to 'pin' the certificate? With this method you don't get the error right? If so, please, rate my answer.

Comment: Mat, I did not got enough time, I will try and let you know. Additional I actually wanted to this happened as I do not wanted to allow user to use app in back date.