# Android java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: java, android, security, ssl, okhttp

There are three hosts that an android app do the authentication and authorization. Final host is the REST API. For the first time using Oauth authentication and authorization process it works without issue.

But if **user kills the app** after login and accessing the services provided by REST API and then again open the app, this issue arise. **In this time authentication and authorization process is not happening, only the REST API.** It caused to `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException` **but it was working during the first use (login and then use the app).**

Can someone explains the scenario behind this exception and whats wrong with the app. This works if certification exceptions are ignored as bellow according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8694377/2341815).

```
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = null;

        try {
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                    TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            // Initialise the TMF as you normally would, for example:
            try {
                tmf.init((KeyStore)null);
            } catch(KeyStoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

            final X509TrustManager origTrustmanager = (X509TrustManager)trustManagers[0];

            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return origTrustmanager.getAcceptedIssuers();
                        }

                        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                            try {
                                origTrustmanager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                            } catch(CertificateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                            try {
                                origTrustmanager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                            } catch(CertificateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            };
            //TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SSL").getTrustManagers();

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sslSocketFactory;
```

I am using Okhttp 3 for the http requests. Any suggestion would help to solve the issue. And please let me know if I use above code snippet, is it a security violation? will it effect to the security of the app?

Comment: Note: Your `checkServerTrusted` implementation is useless as you catch and ignore the CertificateException. Therefore all server certificates (trusted and untrusted) are accepted!

Comment: @Robert thanks for the clarification. Yes **this is insecure and useless in security perspective**, I've found the correct solution as described in my answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I am answering to this to give an idea about the scenario and solution as per the android developer site for others benefit. I have solved this using custom trust manager.

The problem was with the server certificate, it misses intermediate certificate authority. However with the first flow certificate path is completed somehow and result was successful certificate path validation.

There is a solution for this in [android developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#MissingCa). it suggest to use custom trust manager that trusts this server certificate or it suggest to server to include the intermediate CA in the server chain.

custom trust manager. source: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
// Tell the okhttp to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
OkHttpClient okHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory()).build();
```

**UPDATE:** My problem was solved after intermediate certificate authority added to the certificate chain from the server side. It is the best solution, Bundling the certificate with the app requires app to be updated on certificate expiring or any other issues related with certificate management.

**UPDATE:03/09/2017** Easiest way to load certificate file I found is use of raw resource.

```
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(context
                .getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certfilename));
```

where certfilename is the certificate file placed in resources/raw folder. Also okhttp's [`sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory)`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.Builder.html#sslSocketFactory-javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory-) has been deprecated and suggested approach in the okhttp api doc can be used.

Also when getting the certificate from the server it is better to use openssl.

```
openssl s_client -connect {server-address}:{port} -showcerts
```

Because I used to grab that from firefox and faced situation where it was altered by the virus guard.

Answer (score 2):

1. Paste your `cert.pem` in raw folder
2. Create a method

   ```
   private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory(){
       try {
           CertificateFactory cf;
           cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

           Certificate ca;
           InputStream cert = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert);
           ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert);
           cert.close();

           String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
           KeyStore keyStore   = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
           keyStore.load(null, null);
           keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

           String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
           TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
           tmf.init(keyStore);

           SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
           sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

           return sslContext.getSocketFactory();

       }
       catch (Exception e){
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Call like this

   ```
   final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    //pass getSSLSocketFactory() in params
    client.setSslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());

    String appURl = context.getString(R.string.apis_app_url);

    final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(appURl).setClient(new OkClient(client)).
                    build();
   ```

Comment: `setSslSocketFactory` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in my case was lack of part of ssl certificate file(I had several files on my server), solution was just copy and paste all of them inside 1 file and on nginx configuration file give the path to that new file