# Connect to HTTPS from Android - REST and SOAP web service

Tags: android, rest, soap, https

I am facing a problem to call https from Android. Can any one please help with steps to connect to the https server.

I tried to connect to google with https and its working fine but when I try to connect to my local server, I am facing problems.

1. want to connect a RESTful web service with https
2. want to connect a SOAP based web service developed using JAX-WS with https.
3. Code to connect with RESTFul

   ```
   HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

   DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

   SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
   SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
   socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
   registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
   SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

   // Set verifier     
   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

   // Example send http request
    //final String url = "https://encrypted.google.com/";
    final String url = "https://ipaddress:8181/RESTTest/cars";
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
     try{
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println(response);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   ```

   its working fine for google but not working for my server and it's giving

   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
4. Code for connect with SOAP:

   ```
   public String getString(final String methodName, Map<String, Object>        params)        throws     Exception {
   HttpTransportSE httpsTransportSE = new         HttpTransportSE("https://ipaddress:8181/BankingWS/banking?wsdl");

   try {
       SoapObject request = new SoapObject("https://test/",
               methodName);
       if(params != null && params.size() > 0){
           Set<String> keys = params.keySet();
           Iterator<String> iterator = keys.iterator();
           while(iterator.hasNext()){
               String key = iterator.next();
               request.addProperty(key, params.get(key));
               key = null;
           }
       }
       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
               SoapEnvelope.VER11);
       envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

       TrustManagerManipulator.allowAllSSL();
       httpsTransportSE.call(methodName, envelope);

       SoapPrimitive sp = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

       return sp.toString();
   } catch (Exception exception) {
       System.out.println(exception.toString());
       throw exception;
   }
   }
   ```

   In above code using the TrustManagerManipulator from following link:
   http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/allow-untrusted-certificate-for-https.html

This is also not working and when I check the response code it's giving

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'S:Client' faultstring: 'Cannot find dispatch method for {test.WSEndPointPort}authenticate' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

Please help to fix this problem, as I am not able to call https from Android by any way :(

Thank you very much for your time and efforts.

Thank you,
Ishan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a X509TrustManager which bypass all the security check. You can find an example in this similar questions:

[Make a connection to a HTTPS server from Java and ignore the validity of the security certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752266/make-a-connection-to-a-https-server-from-java-and-ignore-the-validity-of-the-secu)

or

[How to ignore SSL certificate errors in Apache HttpClient 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703161/how-to-ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-in-apache-httpclient-4-0/2703233#2703233)

Comment: Hi NeTeInStEiN, Thank you for your reply. Let I check with it in my code. Thank you,

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN if we ignore that does it break any security? Main purpose of using SSL is to secure your communication over the internet. By ignoring does it make any difference?