# Add HTTPS support to download manager

Tags: java, http, https, download-manager

I found a simple download manager [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-create-a-download-manager-in-java.html). It can download from HTTP sites, but doesn't support HTTPS sites. How can I modify it to support HTTPS links?

Comment: Did you see the line about verifyurl. It checks if the protocol is http explicitly. Try removing it.

Comment: while you may have a specific scenario, this is just the same issue as opening an HTTPS connection in java. You need a trust manager to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. Just try an HTTPS URL. The only possible issue will be whether it trusts the server's certificate.

Comment: I do not think so.   // Verify download URL.
    private URL verifyUrl(String url) {
        // Only allow HTTP URLs.
        if (!url.toLowerCase().startsWith("http://"))
            return null;

Comment: So fix that to allow https as well!

Answer (score -1):

This answer will help you.

[Apache HttpClient 4.0 Ignore SSL Certificate Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703161/apache-httpclient-4-0-ignore-ssl-certificate-errors/2703233#2703233)

Comment: in addition to EJP's answer, this will allow you to accept untrusted certificates.

Comment: But he's not using the Apache HttpClient!

Comment: Ok, I removed the explicit HTTP check, but now I'm stuck on the SSL stuff.