# Java/SSL - Unhandle exception:java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, ssl

i also want to know how to  ignore SSL certificate errors in Apache HttpClient 4.0 ,so i read this post：[How to ignore SSL certificate errors in Apache HttpClient 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703161/how-to-ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-in-apache-httpclient-4-0)  and do as it say.

but i got an error in intellij idea in this statement:

```
   SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
```

Unhandle exception:java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException.

i also tried "TLS" but useless.

Please does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this compile error because `SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");` throws a checked exception which you have to take care of.

Either by surrounding the line with a try-catch block:

```
try {
   SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   /// handle e
}
```

or add `throws NoSuchAlgorithmException` to the method definition.

This are Java basics you should learn something about Exceptions: [Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: hank you for actually helping me ^.^