# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target - java

Tags: java, httpclient, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to connect to a website using a [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) object. It works fine for websites we normally use(Like google). But there is a web site, when I try to connect, my program gives this error..

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1369)
....................
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
...............

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 27 more
```

When I try to go to this url from the browser, I have to click **continue anyway**. Otherwise browser will not load the page. It gives a **privacy error** saying **your connection is not private**.

How can I overcome this problem in my java application..? I want my software to connect with that url without any error or without asking any confirmation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore SSL certificate errors in Apache HttpClient 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703161/how-to-ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-in-apache-httpclient-4-0)

Comment: I solved this problem generating a new Cacerts file and adding it to java trustStore.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### `TrustSelfSignedStrategy` approach

The problem was solved when I used a [TrustSelfSignedStrategy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/TrustSelfSignedStrategy.html) object as the Trust material to [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html).

```
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                    .build()
                )
            ).build();
```

#### `TrustAllStrategy` approach

If the above does not work, for example because the certificate served by the server is not a self-signed certificate but just untrusted for other reasons (for example, hostname mismatch), this is an even more brutal approach. **Do not** use this in production, since it will blindly trust *all* certificates. This is typically only useful for unit/integration test and other similar scenarios.

```
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustAllStrategy())
                    .build()
                )
            ).build();
```

Answer (score 14):

For HttpClient4.x, the following will trust all

```
public static HttpClientBuilder createTrustAllHttpClientBuilder() {
  SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
  builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, (chain, authType) -> true);           
  SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new 
  SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build(), NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
  return HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf);
}
```

Comment: what is chain and authype?

Comment: Thanks for this @greensuisse. I adjusted the example provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/30105045/227779 to add a very similar approach to yours: using the `TrustAllStrategy`, which is basically what your "return true" lambda does.