# HTTPS communication with outbound-gateway

Tags: https, spring-integration, outbound

Spring-Integration 4:

I'd like to make communication with http outbound-gateway for HTTPS. i.e. with secure protocol.
Requirement is I'd like to use URL "https://" but we don't have certificate & need to bypass this.

Answer (score 1):

I found in some my old project this config:

```
<bean id="clientHttpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
<!--TODO waiting HttpClient SSL impl <bean id="clientHttpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"/>-->
```

And I remember that such kind of `CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory` for `commons-http-client-3.0` allows to accept all server certificates. Otherwise you should customize `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` for `commons-http-client-4.x`, like this:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE).build()
```

See more info in this answer: [How to ignore SSL certificate errors in Apache HttpClient 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703161/how-to-ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-in-apache-httpclient-4-0).

After that customization you just should inject that `clientHttpRequestFactory` to the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`.

Comment: My sample looks like this:
<int-http:outbound-gateway url="#{myUtil.getMyUrl()}"
                            http-method="POST"
                            expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                            request-factory="factory"
                            request-channel="performXYZ"
                            reply-channel="outputXYZ">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
<bean id="factory"
    class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
  <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000"/>
  <property name="readTimeout" value="10000"/>
</bean>

Comment: @Artem How do I wire CloseableHttpClient in my SpringXML and set SSLContext, please see my question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242723/allowallhostnameverifier-in-spring-integration-xml