# AllowAllHostnameVerifier for HTTPS in Spring Integration XML

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to make an HTTPS REST call using Spring Integration, below is my configuration.

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
        id="Auth Outbound Gateway"
        request-channel="RequestChannel"
        request-factory="sslFactory"
        header-mapper="headerMapper"
        url="https://XX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX/abcd"
        http-method="POST"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<bean id="sslFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
</bean>

<bean id="requestConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig"
      factory-method="custom">
    <property name="socketTimeout" value="10000" />
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000" />
</bean>

<bean id="requestConfig" factory-bean="requestConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" />

<bean id="httpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder"
      factory-method="create">
    <property name="defaultRequestConfig" ref="requestConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="httpClient" factory-bean="httpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" />
```

I am getting the following error...

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <XX.XX.XX.XXX> != <abc.abc.xyz.com>
```

To solve this I wan't to AllowAllHostnameVerifier as I am calling to internal REST services.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER).build();
```

but how do I wire the above java line in my spring configuration xml?

Comment: pls post also the bean httpClient which is referenced in bean sslFactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Custom Java**

```
public class HttpClientFactory extends AbstractFactoryBean<HttpClient> {

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return HttpClient.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpClient createInstance() throws Exception {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        TrustStrategy allTrust = new TrustStrategy() {
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        };

        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().useTLS().loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, allTrust).build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

**XML Configuration**

```
<!--SSL-->
<bean id="sslFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
</bean>
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.springframework.integration.samples.http.HttpClientFactory" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClients.custom()` returns a `HttpClientBuilder` so simply replace that builder bean and the client bean with one of your own that returns the `HttpClient` (after setting the `defaultRequestConfig`).