# Spring Boot calling HTTPS endpoint

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, tomcat8

I've created a Spring Boot application that I'm running as a poor man's daemon to call another Java service on another tomcat instance. I'm getting an SSL error when connecting to the other Java service but if I hit the other service with something like SoapUi(or Postman) using the same URL and headers I get an OK response. So something must be wrong with my Spring Boot configuration.

I'm using the same JKS for Spring Boot and SoapUI. I've tried using the cert in the application.properties as well as specifying it on the command line using `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore` as well as the related password parameter.

When I run the other service locally without SSL I can connect just fine via my Spring Boot application.

The SSL error I'm getting is: `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Netscape cert type does not permit use for SSL server`

Best I can think is that SoapUI(or Postman) identify's itself as a client application and my Spring Boot identifies itself as a server? So *I think* I'm asking how can I make Spring Boot identify itself as a client but I'm still not sure I understand the SSL error to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You have a multitude of problems. First off, soapui doesn't do verification of the server SSL certificate when it connects, java by default does not. You can however configure java client to also ignore server cert verification.

How to ignore depends on what client you use, apache httpclient is the most common one and you can find details on that [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703161/how-to-ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-in-apache-httpclient-4-0).

Now, you should not really do that. Instead, you should have a trust store that contains the certificates that would validate the server cert. In that case you would be interested in *truststore* configuration, not a *keystore* - keystore is for other way around, when you're identifying yourself to some other party. You'd need to import the root CA and intermediate certificates to your trust store, then point to that in your configuration.