# HTTPS POST call not working with RestTemplate or Apache Httpclient 4.x but working with Postman client

Tags: java, rest, post, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

When I call some **https** rest end-point with POST method with necessary headers from postman, then it's working perfect.

I am trying to call the same a REST service with following java based approaches and getting same error (as given below) for all :

1. Using Spring boot(1.5.3) with Rest Template 
   Environment : Windows 7 , java version : 1.8.0_192

Code snippet :

```
String postJsonBody = getJsonBody();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Content-Type","application/json");
headers.add("Authorization", Token);

HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(postJsonBody, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://myservice.url", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
```

2. Using Apache HTTP client with version 4.5.3

Code snippet :

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients
       .custom()
       .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
       .build();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(getURL());

String json = getJsonBody();
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", Token);

CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
client.close();
response.close();
```

Error :

```
    16:28:17.902 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
16:28:17.902 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
16:28:17.902 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: ...][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
16:28:17.904 [main] INFO org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to ... : Connection reset
16:28:17.907 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
```

Can someone please suggest what could be the root cause and fix?

Comment: Most likely the problem is the network, rather than code based. Maybe server certificate is not trusted/expired. Maybe TLS version mismatch. Consider ignoring certificate issues. This way you can rule out problems related to SSL. This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50274496/3523579

Comment: Hi @MikhailKholodkov : Thanks for your response. Yes I also doubt it's something related to SLL problem, but not sure how to fix this. BTW, I have tried almost all approaches mentioned on given url by you, but no luck yet.