# How to ignore SSL certificate errors in Apache HttpComponents HttpClient 5.1

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

How do I bypass certificate verification errors with [Apache HttpComponents HttpClient 5.1](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/)?

I've found a [working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50274496/10108192) to bypass such errors in HttpClient 4.5 that suggests customizing `HttpClient` instance:

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients
            .custom()
            .setSSLContext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE).build())
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
            .build();
```

But it is not applicable to HttpClient 5.1, as `setSSLContext` and `setSSLHostnameVerifier` methods do not exist in [`HttpClientBuilder`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5/5.1/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/HttpClientBuilder.html) (which `HttpClients.custom()` returns).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are several specialized builders in HC 5.1 that can be used to do the same:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
                        .setSslContext(SSLContextBuilder.create()
                                .loadTrustMaterial(TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE)
                                .build())
                        .setHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                        .build())
                .build())
        .build();
```