# How to solve sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException?

Tags: java

I have written some code to connect to my mail server and read emails. I am using POP3 using SSL connection. I have also added SSL certificate to the java keystore. But still i am getting the same exception. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible cause this exception would be the cert from the keystore does not match the cert from the server.

Checkout these link might be helpful to you:

- [Unable to Connect to SSL Services due to PKIX Path Building Failed sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Unable+to+Connect+to+SSL+Services+due+to+PKIX+Path+Building+Failed)
- [How to handle invalid SSL certificates with Apache HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828775/httpclient-and-ssl)

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, I disabled *always scan encrypted connections* in the settings of my antivirus software, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have groovy script, and I was using `@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-collections4', version='4.2')`

I could not runt it because of an error *Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: org.apache.commons#commons-collections4;4.2: not found]*

Using `-Divy.message.logger.level=4` I saw I was having the following problem:

`Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-collections4/4.2/commons-collections4-4.2.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version)`

*My qick fix was to use JDK8 instead of JDK7* it seems that JDK8 has updated certificates and it worked