# javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

In Java mail send am getting following exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1365)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1353)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:794)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:336)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:258)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:137)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:86)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:150)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
    at com.csdcsystems.amanda.common.utility.EmailHelper.sendMail(EmailHelper.java:244)
    at com.csdcsystems.amanda.jems.web.viewmodel.FolderEmailPrintOutputViewModel.sendEmail(FolderEmailPrintOutputViewModel.java:117)
    at com.csdcsystems.amanda.jems.web.viewmodel.FolderEmailPrintOutputViewModel.sendEmail(FolderEmailPrintOutputViewModel.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.ParamCall.call(ParamCall.java:109)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doExecute(BinderImpl.java:1508)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.doCommand(BinderImpl.java:1261)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl.access$1500(BinderImpl.java:95)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener.onEvent0(BinderImpl.java:1145)
    at org.zkoss.bind.impl.BinderImpl$CommandEventListener.onEvent(BinderImpl.java:1103)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:2734)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2705)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2646)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:136)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1709)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1494)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1204)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:558)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:456)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:464)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: **unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target**

See these relevant threads:

[Solutions for SunCertPathBuilderException](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/)

[How to solve sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709540/how-to-solve-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception)

[Allowing Java to use an untrusted certificate for SSL/HTTPS connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201048/allowing-java-to-use-an-untrusted-certificate-for-ssl-https-connection/1201102#1201102)

[Unable to find valid certification path to requested target - error even after cert imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210514/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-error-even-after-c)