# SunCertPathBuilderException despite setting trusr store properties

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, truststore

I need to consume some HTTPS web services. To use the certificate, I'm setting (javax.net.ssl) **trustStore**, **trustStorePassword**, **keyStore** and **keyStorePassword** properties through the *System.setProperty*.

If I do `new URL([HTTPS...WSDL]).openStream()`, it works. So, I'm sure that trust and keystore properties are ok (without setting those properties, my routine failed).

The problem is when I try to consume the service, I'm getting the famous

> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

exception.

Anyone have an idea of what I need to do?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709540/how-to-solve-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception

Comment: Does your trust store include the whole certificate chain of the server certificate (CA->(intermediate)->server cert)? Have you tried without setting the truststore and truststorepass explicitly, i.e. defaulting to the `cacerts` truststore that ships with the JRE? You shouldn't need to specify a truststore if the CA of the server certificate is "well-known".

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible failures:

1. You are using a self-signed certificate.
2. Your certificate has been signed by a common CA (Certificate Authority) using an intermediate certificate, but their intermediate certificate is not served by your web server.
3. Both the server certificate and the CA intermediate certificate are served by your web server, but the Java truststore does not contain the root certificate.

To solve the last step use:
[Import CA root cert](http://connect2id.com/blog/importing-ca-root-cert-into-jvm-trust-store)