# Spring Dashboard: No entries. Check internet connection?

Tags: ssl-certificate, maven-3, firewall, spring-tool-suite, network-connection

[image]

In spring tool suite "internet connection" error is displaying while opening the dashboard of the STS. I have checked internet connectivity in google chrome, mozilla, it is working and connecting to internet. There is no proxy server for internet connection, but behind the Firewall.

[image]

Above configuration is set in STS: Windows-->preferences-->General-->Network Connectivity. "Active Provider" is set to Direct. Still the error is displayed.

One more thing to add, STS IDE integrated browser can access internet, while dashboard can't.

There is no proxy configuration mentioned in the Maven .m2/settings.xml

When clicked on "Getting Started Guide" here is the error displayed "SunCertPathBuilderException":

Checked in Google Chrome Browser for CA certificate existence and found "FirewallName SSL CA"(Here is path where it is cross checked: Google Chrome Browser: Customize and Control Google Chrome-->Settings-->Show Advanced Settings-->HTTPS/SSL-->Manage Certificates-->TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities). Still the error exists:

[image]

Comment: sounds like this could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709540/how-to-solve-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexception

Comment: Already "jssecacerts" file is generated and placed in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security directory which is generated through "InstallCert" java program.