# Android: Work with an unsecure ssl certificate

Tags: android

i am trying to port an existing project to Android and am quite new to the platform.
The communication is done using Ksoap2, a soap library.

When i try to communicate with the server using https i get a SSLHandshakeException:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Is there a way around this? And, if yes, where do i have to start?

Answer (score 1):

Either make sure the site has a proper certificate, or use a TrustManager that accepts any certificate.

For the latter, see [How to handle invalid SSL certificates with Apache HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828775/httpclient-and-ssl)

Comment: I had some difficulties implementing this before, but reviewed it after your link and found the missing code. I still get the same exception as before though. Is there something else i can add?