# HTTPS POST in Java

Tags: java, servlets, https, urlconnection

I have some basic questions about HTTPS POST using java. I don't have experience in writing SSL connections. I will be using JBoss to deploy. Will sharing my servlet name suffice for the HTTPS request to reach my servlet? How will I process a HTTPS request from my servlet will `request.getparameter("param name")` work?. I did some googling and found out that I have to listen to SSL socket. But for different HTTPS request do I have to write different servlet? When I say different its two entirely different request and **NOT** multiple request of same type? I have been trying to understand this concept for sometime now. But I couldn't do so.

This application is a server-client application. there will be no JSP page involved in. It's just my servlets and java class files.

Comment: This post pretty much covers everything you need:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828775/httpclient-and-ssl

Answer (score 1):

Configuring your application server (in your case JBoss) to use HTTPS is a separate matter from what you code in your servlets so feel free to code your application first and then make the changes in your Application Server so it uses HTTPS.

[Here you can find how to enable SSL on JBoss:](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=22243)

Answer (score 0):

SSL protocol negotiated by server and client (browser). Maybe I am wrong, but you do not have to worried about how to process https request. process them just like normal http requests, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly interfacing with the socket, you will have to do the SSL negotiation. In almost all cases, however, when using an "HTTP client", this will be handled for you and you may treat it as you would any other HTTP connection.