# java system properties for proxy fails on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, proxy

I am using system.properties in my java code.
It works perfect on a windows 7 OS but fails on ubuntu12.04.

I used tomcat at both the places.
Any help in this regard will be helpful.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyhost);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyport);        
String encoded = new String(encoder.encode(new String(username+":"+password).getBytes()));
uc.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

Exception:
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479434/server-returned-http-response-code-401-for-url-https this might help

Comment: In the absence of a defined charset the `getBytes()` method will use the platform's default charset to return the `byte[]`. It is possible that information is lost in this process and the wrong base64 encoded `BASIC` auth is sent to the proxy. I'd begin by checking that.

Comment: Thanks all only UTF-8 was missing

Answer (score -1):

The 401 error code indicates "Unauthorized". You could try this:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "yourproxyhost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "yourproxyport");

String credentials = username + ":" + password;
String encoded  = Base64Converter.encode(credentials.getBytes("UTF-8"));
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
uc.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", encoded));
```

Comment: Thanks, only UTF-8 was missing