# Use https ressources to generate pdf (with Flying Saucer / itext)

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

I want to create a pdf from html with external resources (jpg, css).

Here is the code used to generated the pdf File object, with Flying Saucer and itext :

```
ITextRenderer iTextRenderer = new ITextRenderer();
iTextRenderer.setDocumentFromString(xhtmlString);
iTextRenderer.layout();

File file = new File("test.pdf");
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
iTextRenderer.createPDF(os);
os.close();
```

Unfortunatly, all the resources linked with **https** are ignored, while **http** resources work well.

**EDIT :**

I extended ITextUserAgent to intercept the https call resources, and I got this error :

> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

So I need to have a certificate to get those https resources.

[Here](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Problems-with-Images-and-SSL-td3051935.html) is exactly the same problem than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135074/download-file-from-https-server-using-java) is a link to a java-native way of loading data from HTTPS servers.

Right now, you're using Flying Saucer's implementation of XML parsing, which doesn't seem to reference much HTTPS support in its documentation. I would use the above workaround, and then pass the DOM to the Renderer directly.