# Can't download file with Playwright Chromium or Webkit

Tags: java, web-scraping, webkit, chromium, playwright

I want to download some file for example [sitemap.xml.gz](https://www.fnac.es/sitemap-top-post.xml.gz).
I want to do it only with [playwright 1.22](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-download).
I tried to do it with **chromium browser**, but it **fails**.
Also it doesn't work with **webkit**. With webkit it opens **all file content on the page** and gives me **timeout**.
It only works with **firefox**.
But I want to know that is wrong with others browsers? Maybe it is some **bug in playwright**.
Has anyone been able to download directly a file with playwright?

```java
public class PwDownload {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) {
            final BrowserType chromium = playwright.chromium();
            final Browser browser = chromium.launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(false));
            Page page = browser.newPage();
            Download download = page.waitForDownload(() -> {
                page.navigate("https://www.fnac.es/sitemap-top-post.xml.gz");
            });
            System.out.println(download.path());
            browser.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error trace with chromium:**

```
navigating to "https://www.fnac.es/sitemap-top-post.xml.gz", waiting until "load"
============================================================
    at FrameSession._navigate (/private/var/folders/1n/tnrrsqrs1_7f_k2x84xql3pr0000gn/T/playwright-java-12123589937209992525/package/lib/server/chromium/crPage.js:636:35)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:437:9)
    at async /private/var/folders/1n/tnrrsqrs1_7f_k2x84xql3pr0000gn/T/playwright-java-12123589937209992525/package/lib/server/frames.js:648:30
    at async ProgressController.run (/private/var/folders/1n/tnrrsqrs1_7f_k2x84xql3pr0000gn/T/playwright-java-12123589937209992525/package/lib/server/progress.js:101:22)
    at async FrameDispatcher.goto (/private/var/folders/1n/tnrrsqrs1_7f_k2x84xql3pr0000gn/T/playwright-java-12123589937209992525/package/lib/server/dispatchers/frameDispatcher.js:86:59)
    at async DispatcherConnection.dispatch (/private/var/folders/1n/tnrrsqrs1_7f_k2x84xql3pr0000gn/T/playwright-java-12123589937209992525/package/lib/server/dispatchers/dispatcher.js:352:22)
}
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.Connection.dispatch(Connection.java:183)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.Connection.processOneMessage(Connection.java:163)
    at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.ChannelOwner.runUntil(ChannelOwner.java:101)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: link that you posted - shows access denied (from any browser, doesn't matter -  local or automated): https://i.imgur.com/JWLL31x.png . Could you please provide another link to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for Chromium and Firefox. Change `outputDirectory` variable before running.

```
import com.microsoft.playwright.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) {
            String outputDirectory = "d:\\";

            String url = "https://www.johnlewis.com/sitemap/products/products-00.xml.gz";
            String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(url);

            BrowserType browserType = playwright.firefox();
            Browser browser = browserType.launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(false));
            BrowserContext newContext = browser.newContext(new Browser.NewContextOptions().setAcceptDownloads(true));
            Page page = newContext.newPage();

            Download download = page.waitForDownload(() -> {
                page.evaluate("(y) => {location.href = y;}", url);
            });

            Path downloadedFilePath = download.path();
            System.out.println("Downloaded to " + downloadedFilePath);

            Path destinationFilePath = Paths.get(outputDirectory, filename);
            FileUtils.copyFile(new File(downloadedFilePath.toString()), new File(destinationFilePath.toString()));
            System.out.println("Saved to " + destinationFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

As for `webkit`, I guess there is some kind of built in browser functionality you cannot override. You can even try to open `webkit` using Playwright's java code and then insert a link manually and try to download - it doesn't allow you to do this (even in separate window, or even using javascript + `download` html attribute)

Comment: It works on **chromium**, on firefox it worked with the code in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Only one thing **acceptDownloads = true** it is a default value you don't need to set it.

Comment: Hm, strange, it didn't work without setAcceptDownloads(true) in chromium. And as I see from docs - false is default value: https://i.imgur.com/vjanbwz.png. If it works on your computer without this property set to `true` then it is cool.

Comment: I have true as default value. https://ibb.co/YXQTVrh Maybe you have other **PW version**. I have PW v1.22.

Comment: Haha, that's funny. I am using `compile 'com.microsoft.playwright:playwright:1.17.0'`. Don't know what to say, just glad it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a link to your file, then why you don't just download it via a normal connection? [Download file from HTTPS server using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135074/download-file-from-https-server-using-java)

Playwright Downloads are like downloads triggered from a page or by a user. Just visiting a link isn't going to trigger a download event.

Comment: Because I need to do it explicitly with PW. Thanks