# How to connect to a URL without certification problems?

Tags: java, html, security, ssl, url

**Introduction**

**I want to be able to retrieve the source page** from a website to work on the data. Some webs let me connect to them but the are some which throws at me `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I want to mention that **I do not own the website** which I am scraping data from* (as some of the solutions I have read so far mentions server owning stuff)*

Moreover, I am still learning and I have some questions, do not be too technical I just want to have this problem sorted out.

**Problem**

Java doesn't seem to trust the website so throws me the Exception below. I have read some answers here but nothing worked so far.

**What I have done so far**

I imported the website's certificate needed as:

```
keytool -import -alias virto -file /path to crt/ -keystore virtocert
```

Then restarted PC but still getting this Exception error. When I run my code.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1478)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1050)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at HttpsClientUtil.main(HttpsClientUtil.java:23)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1460)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 19 more
C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Java\WebScraper_03\WebScraper\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1339: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Java\WebScraper_03\WebScraper\nbproject\build-impl.xml:980: Java returned: 1
```

**Code**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String httpsURL = "https://virtonomics.com/";
        String FILENAME = "c:\\temp\\filename.html";
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME));
        URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty ( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0" );
        InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins, "Windows-1252");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String inputLine;

        // Write each line into the file
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            bw.write(inputLine);
        }
        in.close(); 
        bw.close();
    }
```

**What else do I need to do in order to sort out this problem?**

Thanks for the interest in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either set up your own keystore and have the certs validated or you could choose to ignore the certs completely.

You can have a look at this post for the various options: [Ignore SSL Certificate Errors with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060250/ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-with-java)