# Do I Really Need to Import a SSL Cert into Java Keystore Manually?

Tags: java, ssl, https, box

I have a Java web app that has been running fine for several months. It integrates with the Box API (https://upload.box.com/api/2.0) to save files to the cloud service. Out of the blue, we started receiving the dreaded `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated` exception while trying to make a REST API call to the Box web service.

There are tons of posts out there that tell you how to manually import the cert into your key store using the keytool utility. I understand that I can do this to fix the problem. But is this really the correct fix?

The fact that my application has been running fine for months leads me to believe something in the certificate at https://upload.box.com changed. Looking at the cert in my web browser, the certificate seems valid and was only renewed a few weeks ago. What is missing from my keystore?

Is it the Root CA certificate that is missing from my keystore? If that is the case, could I just copy the cacerts file from newer version of Java? My app is currently running JDK 1.6.0_33.

I am just trying to understand why this would suddenly stop working and what the "real" fix should be. It doesn't seem like modifying the JDK keystore is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just assume you're using Apache HTTP Client 4.x, before [4.2.6, 4.3 Beta2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1346), in which case `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated` is most likely to come from a certificate that isn't trusted (otherwise it means the server didn't send a cert, which is a different problem, [more details in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12096398/372643)).

The current cert for server you're trying to access seems to have been issued on 07/04/2014, so this indicates that the certificate, and perhaps its chain has changed recently indeed.

I don't have a JDK 1.6.0_33 at hand, but it's possible that some of these CA certs were not part of the default bundle. In any case, it's worth updating `cacerts`, even on older JREs (if only to remove CA certs that should no longer be trusted, for example). The [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) clearly states (admittedly in the middle of a fairly long document, but it's worth searching for "important note"...):

> **IMPORTANT NOTE: The JDK ships with a limited number of trusted root certificates in the `<java-home>/lib/security/cacerts` file. As documented in keytool, it is your responsibility to maintain (that is, add/remove) the certificates contained in this file if you use this file as a truststore.**
>
> Depending on the certificate configuration of the servers you contact, you may need to add additional root certificate(s). Obtain the needed specific root certificate(s) from the appropriate vendor.

If you can't upgrade your JRE (Java 6 is in general out of support), updating the `cacerts` file from a more recent version is certainly a sensible compromise.

Besides the various fixes in Java 7, Java 7+ would also allow you to connect to hosts that require SNI (although this doesn't seem to be the case for this particular host).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Based on the commend in the JSSE Reference Guide - "it is your responsibility to maintain (that is, add/remove) the certificates contained in this file if you use this file as a truststore", I have gone ahead and added the new cert to the keystore.