# where is ssl.SslContextFactory?

Tags: ssl, jetty

Someone PLEASE HELP! I am going crazy searching for ssl.SslContextFactory.

History:
- Am using artifactory2.66 which uses jetty 7.02 ( I can't use higher version of artifactory because of java 1.7 dependency)
- To make artifactory run as https, I did the following:

```
    <Call name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
               <Set name="Port">8443</Set>
               <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
               <Set name="keystore">/amyhomedir/artifactory/etc/keystore</Set>
               <Set name="password">password</Set>
               <Set name="keyPassword">password</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
```

This worked but my jenkins did not recognize the new http url and threw `"Error occurred while requesting version information: peer not authenticated"`. I wondered if this is due to depricated methods of ssl.SslSocketConnector and decided to use the following code as per [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL)

```
   <Call name="addConnector">
     <Arg>
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
         <Arg>
           <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl.SslContextFactory">
             <Set name="keyStore"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
             <Set name="keyStorePassword">mypassword</Set>
             <Set name="keyManagerPassword">mypassword</Set>
             <Set name="trustStore"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/keystore</Set>
             <Set name="trustStorePassword">mypassword</Set>
           </New>
         </Arg>
         <Set name="port">8443</Set>
         <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
       </New>
     </Arg>
   </Call>
```

But I always get class not found exception for ssl.SslContextFactory.. I also tried util.ssl.SslContextFactory.. Nothing works! I am not able to find out the correct ssl.SslContextFactory... 
Please help!

Comment: My guess would be that Jenkins is using a version of Apache HTTP Client that has the problem described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12096398/372643), i.e. you get this error because the client connecting to your repository isn't configured to trust its certificate. AFAIK the `SslContextFactory` is for later versions of Jetty, effectively replacing the settings you already have. I'd try to make your client (whatever is running within Jetty) trust your server certificate instead.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I am trying that route too. its another nightmare!

Comment: Importing your server certificate into your the `cacerts` file of the JRE used by your Jenkins installation should do.

Comment: Thanks. I did it and it worked. Do you want to leave your comment as an answer so that I could choose your answer as the solution to my question?