# spring cloud ribbon client to connect to ssl

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon

I am using Spring Cloud, and `RestTemplate` to connect to micro services using SSL.

When I do:

```
restTemplate.exchange("https://myservice/properties", HttpMethod.GET,null, String.class)
```

it is using `RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory`.

I got:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:421)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_72]

Comment: have to define @FeignClient("https://myservice") to work with https, and it works like a charm

Comment: I suspect that this is just a general `RestTemplate` https problem.  Did you google that exception?  I found this stack overflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095758/apache-httpclient-sslpeerunverifiedexception

Comment: yes, it is resolved. and now I am switching over to use FeignClient. never knew that FeignClient needs to define as "https" with the service name if micro services are using  SSL.

Comment: the reason is they use different http clients underneath.  The one configured with `RestTemplate` is more secure in that it doesn't accept ssl that it doesn't know about, the one that Feign uses by default is less secure by default, it ignores security errors with ssl.

Comment: the way to resolve is to configure ribbon client isSecure=true, and create a custom socket factory to accept the SSL cert