# Apache Http Client SSL certificate error

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I know it's been asked before but I tried all the solutions that I found and it's still not working.

Basically, I'm trying to get some content via Apache Http Client (4.3) and the website that I'm connecting is having some SSL issues.

First, I was getting and `SSLException` with and `unrecognized_name` message. I tried to get around this by setting the `jsse.enableSNIExtension` property to `false`.

Then, I got this exception:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I then tried supplying my won `SSLFactory` that would accept all certificates but I'm still getting the same exception. Here's my code:

```
private static void sslTest() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .useTLS()
            .build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory connectionFactory =
            new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());

    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(connectionFactory)
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .build();

    URI uri = new URIBuilder()
            .setScheme("https")
            .setHost(BASE_URL)
            .build();

    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri), RESPONSE_HANDLER);
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please look at my answer in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45734000/8477758

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore SSL certificate errors in Apache HttpClient 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703161/how-to-ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-in-apache-httpclient-4-0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please also note that trusting self-signed certs does not mean trusting any arbitrary cert.

Try setting up your SSL context this way:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, 
    new TrustStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean isTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) 
        throws CertificateException {
            return true;
        }
    })
    .useTLS()
    .build();
```

Please also note that generally trusting certificates indiscriminately defeats the purpose of using SSL in the first place. Use when absolutely necessary or for testing only

Comment: worked like a charm. With `HttpClientBuilder` this is how to create an instance -  `SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
           CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();`

Answer (score 11):

In Http Client 4.5.2:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, 
    new TrustStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean isTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) 
        throws CertificateException {
            return true;
        }
    }).build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf;
sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
```

And then:

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your truststore doesn't trust the server certificate.

Allowing all hostname is an HTTPS step that can only be invoked *if* the certificate is trusted.

Answer (score 0):

The following is for Apache 4x to trust everything

```
static {
    // avoid error javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
    System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
}

public static HttpClientBuilder createTrustAllHttpClientBuilder() {
    try {
        SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
        builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, (chain, authType) -> true);
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build(), NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

        return HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf);
    }
    catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```