# Obtain response code for HTTPS connection

Tags: java, ssl, https, urlconnection

I am trying to check weather my jboss server is up or not or **simply url is reachable or not**. I am achieving same using responseCode i.e. `200` for OK. I am able to do for HTTP but fails for HTTPS.
  So I want the responseCode for HTTPS.

I am using below code

```
        HttpURLConnection urlCon = null;
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/abc");
        urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        System.out.println(urlCon.getResponseCode());
        if(urlCon.getResponseCode() == 200)
        {
            System.out.println("Server is up");
        }
```

works fine for `HTTP` but when I am trying same for `HTTPS` It gives connection refuse or SSLhandshakeException

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
    at com.de.base.tools.Sample.main(Sample.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:462)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
    ... 9 more
```

I have tried `HttpURLConnection` to `HttpsURLConnection` but gives same

anybody know how to get `responceCode()` for `HTTPS`

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the correct port for HTTPS? Servers that have HTTP on 8080 _usually_ have HTTPS on 8443 (although nothing requires this).

Comment: I have config apache and is listing port is 443

Comment: You said you're trying to connect to Jboss, not Apache. Which is it? Apache typically uses the standard ports, 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS; Jboss typically does not.

Comment: apache is my load balancer and I config server to HTTPS using it

Comment: So Apache is listening _for SSL_ on 443, and forwarding to Jboss? And your Java is connecting to the hostname where Apache runs, and port 443, and getting this error? If so: (1) try the `javax.net.debug` log as Hrabosh said and add it to your Q (don't put critical information in comments, they are sometimes deleted) (2) Try a browser (or several browsers) or other clients (curl, wget, openssl s_client, gnutls-cli) connecting to the Apache hostname and port 443.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is problem with self-signed certs which are not in your trust store.
You can check it when you run your client with this:
`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`
Its enable debug for ssl and you will have a better output of error.
If you want to fix problem with self-signed cert, you have to add it to your trusted Java key store.
I think in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828775/how-to-handle-invalid-ssl-certificates-with-apache-httpclient) question are your answers for this.

Comment: Error still persist

Comment: I referred  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828775/how-to-handle-invalid-ssl-certificates-with-apache-httpclient)

Comment: Some SSL/TLS errors are caused by certificates, of all kinds both self-signed and CA-signed, but some are not, and if you look at the actual exception in this case it is absolutely not caused by any certificate.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Why not? I wrote just I think because it is most common problem. But without correct output with enabled ssl debug it is only my opinion :)

Comment: Exceptions due to a cert problem identify the problem as a cert problem, like `ValidatorException` in the Q you link, and occur within routines in the stacktrace that are involved with cert checking, like `ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate` and `X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted` and `PKIXValidator.engineValidate` there.

Comment: Yes, but for this you should have to enabled ssl debug, shouldnt you? Maybe I am wrong, but I think that this will appear only with this ssl debug enabled

Comment: The exception is the same regardless of debug setting. Whether the exception is displayed with the stacktrace can depend on your code, which _could_ look at the debug setting, but this OP posted the stacktrace and clearly did not have the debug setting.