# https digest request failing with security exception

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, digest-authentication

I am using the Aapache httpclient code to read for a url that has Digest authentication. I'm getting a security violation. This url/username/password works fine in a browser. What's wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user/passwd";
    String username = "user";
    String password = "passwd";

    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("fake", "fake_value");
    cookie.setDomain("httpbin.org");
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);


    // get the host
    HttpHost httpHost = URIUtils.extractHost(new URI(url));

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(httpHost.getHostName(), httpHost.getPort()), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
            .build();

    // Create AuthCache instance
    // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
    AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", "support@windward.net");
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", calculateNonce());
    authCache.put(httpHost, digestAuth);

    // Add AuthCache to the execution context
    HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
    localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);


    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    response = httpClient.execute(httpHost, httpGet, localContext);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
        throw new IOException("Error: " + response.getStatusLine() + ". Reading url " + url);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
}

private static synchronized String calculateNonce() {

    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:hh:mm:ss");
    String fmtDate = f.format(d);
    Random rand = new Random(100000);
    Integer randomInt = rand.nextInt();
    return org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(fmtDate + randomInt.toString());
}
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
>     at
>   net.windward.util.AccessProviders.SampleDigestRequest.main(SampleDigestRequest.java:82)
>   Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
>   building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59052',
>   transport: 'socket'   at
>   sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1428)
>     ... 19 more Caused by:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
>     at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
>     ... 25 more

Comment: It seems that the certificate you're using on your server for tls/ssl is not trusted by your jdk. It's common for self-signed certificates, for example. While browser will often let you proceed in such case, jdk drops such connections by default.

Comment: @korolar ok I don't understand something. Why do I need a certificate to access a website? They need a certificate, but why do I need one?

Comment: You don't need a certificate. You need to *trust* a website's certificate.

Comment: @korolar - oh, that makes sense. Is there a way to say I trust any website so it will handle self-signed websites?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1828840.

Comment: @korolar - thank you very much. If you put all the above in an answer I'm happy to set it as the answer.