# Regd httpclient.executeMethod(request); throws an IOException on server , whereas runs on local eclipse

Tags: java, apache, https, ioexception

Tried searching our blog but was not able to find some pointers so posting,

I was just working on a httpsClient Post method code as below and facing `IOException`. little Pointers may help , dont require detailed answers.

```java
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();         
              request = new PostMethod("https://ref.net/auth/token?grant_type=password");             
              request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic KolokYrZTo=");
              request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

          NameValuePair[] data = {
                  new NameValuePair("username", "abc"),
                  new NameValuePair("password", "123"),
                  new NameValuePair("grant_type", "password"),
          };

          request.setRequestBody(data);
          httpclient.executeMethod(request);
 } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  logger.error( "IOException in post()...."+e.getMessage());                
              }
```

I am running this code on eclipse with commons-httpClient 3.1.jar it runs perfectly fine, But when i move my code to server and try to run the same code, the  `httpclient.executeMethod(request);` throws IOException.  To my surprise the `e.printStackTrace();` does not prints as `e` object  itself is `null`
How do i catch this exception and debug this, I am doing something wrong here.

> On my local i have Java1.8 but running at compiler compliance level
>   1.6- On server. I tried running both 1.8 and 1.6 same error.

Comment: is it related to some certificates, which we may have to configure on server and are present on local ?,   i did not add any certificates though

Comment: If `e` is really`null` as you say, the whole thing should subsequently throw a `NullPointerException` when you do `e.printStackTrace` so I have doubts that this is actually the case. I assume that you are referring to what you see in your log. But there you are just adding `e.getMessage()` which might be null. Log the complete exception (so the type of exception being thrown and the stacktrace are logged as well) and add it here, so more can be said about your problem.

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1937)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)

Answer (score 0):

With the error message you added as comment it is clear what's happening here. The server you're connecting to is using a server certificate that the JVM you're using on the command shell doesn't know about.

If you search for this error message in combination with `commons httpclient` you can find a couple of pages discussion this, e.g. one at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828775/how-to-handle-invalid-ssl-certificates-with-apache-httpclient).