# How to handle invalid SSL certificate with Apache client 4.5.5?

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to use Apache Client 4.5.5 to connect to one of my web server.

I am trying to use SSLContextBuilder but it seems its deprecated now, I don't want to use deprecated.

Can someone suggest what are the latest way to handle Invalid certification?

Below is my code it works fine but SSLContext, SSLContextBuilder, loadTrustmaterial are deprecated.

```
SSLContextBuilder sscb = new SSLContextBuilder();
sscb.loadTrustMaterial(null, new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
SSLContext sslContext = sscb.build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory =
        new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier());

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()     
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
        .setConnectionManager(connectionMgr)
        .build();        

try {
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myURL");
```

Answer (score 5):

**Apache HttpClient 4.5.5**

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients
            .custom()
            .setSSLContext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE).build())
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
            .build();
```