# unable to find valid certification path to requested target protocol https

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

the **filePath** is With **Https** protocol and my code is

**URL link =new URL(filePath);**
**InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());**
**i 'm using the jdk1.8.0_211**
[I am getting this error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEAg5.png)

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
at com.km.app.web.service.ImprimanteService.print(ImprimanteService.java:32)
at com.km.app.web.controller.ImprimanteController.print(ImprimanteController.java:43)
```

Comment: Can you please share how are you storing the filePath here?

Comment: Remember to always provide the error message (or maybe only the relevant part of it) here as text instead of a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: the file path is a Url with a https protocol is https://www.nissanusa.com/content/dam/Nissan/us/vehicle-brochures/2019/2019-gt-r-brochure-en.pdf

Comment: have your tried the answers here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828775/how-to-handle-invalid-ssl-certificates-with-apache-httpclient
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Comment: thank you it works  from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore 

 with the Option 1